# Multi-Field Relationship in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with two tables like this:

Stores:

```
+----+-------+--------+-------+-----------+
| ID | Store | County | State | County_ID |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-----------+
| 21 | Name1 | Who    | NV    |           |
| 32 | Name2 | What   | NY    |           |
| 73 | Name3 | When   | MA    |           |
| 44 | Name4 | Where  | FL    |           |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Counties:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | County | State |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | Who    | NV    |  
|  2 | What   | NY    | 
|  3 | Where  | FL    |  
|  4 | When   | MA    |  
+----+--------+-------+
```

I want the County_ID field to reflect the correct ID for the county that the store is in. In this example it should be 1,2,4,3

I tried using an update query to manually update it

```
UPDATE Stores
SET County_ID = (SELECT Counties.ID FROM Counties 
                 WHERE Stores.County=Counties.County AND Stores.State=Counties.State)
```

but I got the error 'Operation must use an updateable query,' which is an ongoing bug with Access. Does anyone have a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: After you've updated the `County_ID` remember to remove the `County` and `State` fields from `Stores` table as these will now be referenced through the `County_ID` _Foreign Key_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error could be caused by various reasons.

Try this query instead: (I don't have MS Access at the moment, but this may work)

```
UPDATE Stores
    INNER JOIN Counties ON Stores.County = Counties.County AND Stores.State = Counties.State
   SET County_ID = Counties.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is not a bug. Rather, in Access, every part of an `Update` query must be updateable, even the subqueries, which rarely are.

In addition to the answer by Paul T (which should work), you can use the following code:

```
UPDATE Stores
SET County_ID = DLookUp("Counties.ID", "Counties", "Counties.County = '" & Stores.County & "' AND Counties.State = '" & Stores.State & "'")
```

`DLookUp` is a way to safely return the first result of a `SELECT` query (first argument = `SELECT` part, second `FROM` part, third `WHERE` part) without causing errors with update locks or multiple return values.

The main advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require an update lock on the `Counties` table. The main disadvantages are that it often is slower, and that if you use string fields, there's a risk of SQL injection, which may make the statement fail.

Answer (score 0):

This Update Query will only update matching records, Stores Counties.ID into Stores.County_ID Field

```
UPDATE Stores
SET [Stores].[County_ID] = [Counties].[ID]
WHERE (([Stores].[County]=[Counties].[County] And [Stores].[State]=[Counties].[State]));
```

Use an Append Query to add Counties that do not Exists after initial update
Be sure to normalize data to avoid creating duplicates due to misspelling and spaces

```
INSERT INTO Counties (County, State)
SELECT DISTINCT Stores.County, Stores.State
FROM Stores
WHERE Stores.County_ID IS NULL;
```

Then run update query to have all County_ID keys filled in